# Indoor location tracking in Android

Tags: android, location, tracking

I need to create an app for Android that can see someone's location indoors. Much like WifiSlam. I would like to know the location and Height/Level inside the building. Is there any technique I should really take a look at? I had an idea about using the different AP's in a building to have a sense of what direction to go to, but is there an easier or more accurate way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

indoo.rs offers an SDK for indoor localization (and navigation). You should give that a try!

PS: I work for indoo.rs.